# Is it possible to make a table with y axis labels of Highcharts bar chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create something similar to the below but using Highcharts bar chart.

[image]

I can't seem to find any implementation like this that utilises highcarts, but was wondering if anyone has come across this or a workaround to create a table joined to the chart?

My data would differ and therefore the number of rows output could be between 1 and 20.

Example of the basic bar provided by [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)

Comment: It is possible to use renderer.text method for creating similar chart: 

http://jsfiddle.net/haahm2ku/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution I can think of is positioning two divs inside the table like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:20px;><div style="width:48%;height:20px;background:blue;"></div></div>
```

and then you can alter the `width` style attribute of the second div.

Comment: thanks. looking around, that does appear to be the most common solution.

Comment: You can also use the `meter` tag, but it is only supported in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even better solution:

```
<progress min="10" value="22" max="100">
```

check it out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp